# How to duplicate 1000 rows of data in Oracle Database table and change just the value of 1 field?

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I have 1000 rows in this one table in an Oracle Database. I need to duplicate those 1000 row in the same table and just change the value of 1 field in the new 1000 additional rows. The PK is tracked by a sequence

I did select * from "that_table" and saved as insert statement in Toad to generate 1000 insert statement but it is a pain to change the PK field value to sequence.nextval. I can just find and replace value the field I want to change.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for an `INSERT ... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO table_name( pk_column, <<other columns>> )
  SELECT sequence_name.nextval, <<other columns>>  
    FROM table_name
```

Comment: @paqogomez - True, but that's not part of the question.  The question states that the table has 1000 rows and that the goal is to duplicate each of the rows but change the value of one column.  If the table had more than 1000 rows and the goal was to duplicate a subset of 1000 rows, we'd need to know which 1000 rows should be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

To add the 1000 rows. You can just insert into table, the query

For example.

```
INSERT INTO table_name [(col1, col2,...)]
    SELECT col1, col2, ....
    FROM tabke
    WHERE .....
```

Now to change the one row, you can just use an update clause.

For example:

```
 UPDATE table
 SET col1 = value1....
 WHERE ....
```